# jquery how can I use variables and strings to make this simpler

Tags: jquery, string, variables, simplify

How can I use variables and strings to make this simpler

```
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Kitchen")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Bathroom")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Decorating")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("DIY")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Garden")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Homeware")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Lighting")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
      $('#department_categories h4:contains("Christmas")').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
```

Comment: Bette ask at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var homeObjects = ["Kitchen", "Bathroom", "Decorating","DIY","Garden","Homeware","Lighting","Christmas"];
var i;
for(i=0;i<homeObjects.length;i++)
{
    $('#department_categories h4:contains('+homeObjects[i]+'])').parent().css('background-image', 'url("some-image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jignesh

I have images for each category. In your example above how does homeObjects (var) work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only using this once per page, you can make sure that the file name is correlating to the `<h4/>` text:

```
var backgroundImage = '/path/to/image/' + $('#department_categories h4').text() + '.jpg';
$('#department_categories h4').parent().css('background-image', 'url("' + backgroundImage + '")');
```

However, if you are wanting loop through several different `<h4/>` within different parent containers, you can run an each loop:

```
$('#department_categories h4').each(function() {
    var backgroundImage = '/path/to/image/' + $(this).text() + '.jpg';
    $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("' + backgroundImage + '")');
});
```

I would suggest using a regex if some of your titles have spaces or special characters:

```
var backgroundImage = '/path/to/image/' + $('#department_categories h4').text().replace(/\W+/g, '-') + '.jpg';
$('#department_categories h4').parent().css('background-image', 'url("' + backgroundImage + '")');
```

OR

```
$('#department_categories h4').each(function() {
    var backgroundImage = '/path/to/image/' + $(this).text().replace(/\W+/g, '-') + '.jpg';
    $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("' + backgroundImage + '")');
});
```

Personally, if you are going to do this over multiple `<h4/>` parent containers, I would lowercase the text:

```
$('#department_categories h4').each(function() {
    var backgroundImage = '/path/to/image/' + $(this).text().replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
    $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("' + backgroundImage + '")');
});
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/daerik/pen/YpVgQB)

Comment: You're a star @Daerik, worked a treat!

One more question - Atm the hyphens start and end on each filename (i.e -image-.jpg), How do I add a static name before and after? Or stop regexp putting hyphens at the start or end?

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out.